# How to convert integers 0-80 to point coordinates (0,0) -> (8,8)?

Tags: java, for-loop, integer, coordinates, point

I'm coding up a Sudoku solving program and have a double for loop for iterating through all the coordinate points from (0,0) to (8,8), 9x9=81 cells in total. I'm trying to write my values into the cells with a string of digits, but can't find any useful methods apart from `.charAt(i)`, which doesn't work.

I'm using a double for loop `(for i = 0; i < 9; i++)` and `(for j = 0; j < 9; j++)` to iterate through my coordinates `new Point(i,j)`.

Does anyone know how to convert integers from 0-80 to point coordinate form (preferably without double for loops).

```
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                        if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                            sb.append(
                                    sudokuPuzzle.getSudokuCell(new Point(j, i)).toString().substring(76, 77));
                        } else if (i == 0 && j == 1 || i == 1 && j == 0) {
                            sb.append(
                                    sudokuPuzzle.getSudokuCell(new Point(j, i)).toString().substring(77, 78));
                        } else if (i == 0 && j < 9 || i == 1 && j == 1 || i >= 2 && j == 0) {
                            sb.append(
                                    sudokuPuzzle.getSudokuCell(new Point(j, i)).toString().substring(78, 79));
                        } else if (i == 1 && j < 9 || i >= 2 && j == 1) {
                            sb.append(
                                    sudokuPuzzle.getSudokuCell(new Point(j, i)).toString().substring(79, 80));
                        } else if (i >= 2 && j < 9 || i >= 2 && j == 1) {
                            sb.append(
                                    sudokuPuzzle.getSudokuCell(new Point(j, i)).toString().substring(80, 81));
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(sb);


                // for all sudoku cells
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                        System.out.println(sb.charAt(i));
                        int nextValue = sb.charAt(i);

                        if (nextValue != 0) {
                            // get next sudoku cell
                            SudokuCell sudokuCell = sudokuPuzzle.getSudokuCell(new Point(j, i));
                            // set values
                            sudokuCell.setValue(nextValue);
                            sudokuCell.setIsInitial(true);
                            sudokuPuzzle.removePossibleValue(sudokuCell);
                            sudokuCell.clearPossibleValues();
                            sudokuFrame.repaintSudokuPanel();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the mapping `i -> (i / 9, i % 9)`, which corresponds to the normal mapping you'd expect.

Comment: It didn't work for some reason, but that's a great idea, I knew it would be something to do with modulo haha